# How To use fail2ban for Nginx?

Tags: security, nginx, fail2ban

How can I use fail2ban on an Nginx server? What are the rules to put in the jails.conf?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Start with below
http://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/554-How-to-Secure-an-nginx-Server-with-Fail2Ban

New filter in /etc/fail2ban/nginx-dos.conf:

```
# Fail2Ban configuration file
#
# Generated on Fri Jun 08 12:09:15 EST 2012 by BeezNest
#
# Author: Yannick Warnir
#
# $Revision: 1 $
#

[Definition]
# Option:  failregex
# Notes.:  Regexp to catch a generic call from an IP address.
# Values:  TEXT
#
failregex = ^<HOST> -.*"(GET|POST).*HTTP.*"$

# Option:  ignoreregex
# Notes.:  regex to ignore. If this regex matches, the line is ignored.
# Values:  TEXT
#
ignoreregex =
```

In our jail.local, we have (at the end of the file):

```
[nginx-dos]
# Based on apache-badbots but a simple IP check (any IP requesting more than
# 240 pages in 60 seconds, or 4p/s average, is suspicious)
# Block for two full days.
# @author Yannick Warnier
enabled = true
port    = http,8090
filter  = nginx-dos
logpath = /var/log/nginx/*-access.log
findtime = 60
bantime  = 172800
maxretry = 240
```

Of course, in case you would be logging all resources of your site (images, css, js, etc), it would be really easy to get to those numbers as a normal user. To avoid this, use the access_log off directive of Nginx, like so:

```
 # Serve static files directly
        location ~* \.(png|jpe?g|gif|ico)$ {
                expires 1y;
                access_log off;
                try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
                gzip off;
        }
        location ~* \.(mp3)$ {
                expires 1y;
                access_log off;
                gzip off;
        }
        location ~* \.(css)$ {
                expires 1d;
                access_log off;
        }
        location ~* \.(js)$ {
                expires 1h;
                access_log off;
        }
```

Comment: nginx-dos.conf should be in filter.d folder right?

Comment: late response but for anyone else that sees this... yes in filter.d