# Fail2ban configuration for nginx using firewallcmd in CentOS 7

Tags: nginx, fail2ban, centos7, firewalld

Previously I have a CentOS 6.5 with Iptables and I configure some jails for nginx as suggested here: [How To use fail2ban for Nginx?](https://serverfault.com/questions/420895/how-to-use-fail2ban-for-nginx).

But now I am in CentOS 7, trying to use the new firewall and latest fail2ban as well. I know there is a new `firewallcmd-ipset.conf`. But I wonder how the code of the above link should be adapted to the new firewall and the new fail2ban.

Watching `firewallcmd-ipset.conf` it seems it also expects the variables `port` and `name`. So maybe it is as easy as replacing `iptables-multiport` by `firewallcmd-ipset`.

Thoughts?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What is the exact problem you are facing with? What have you tried? Please provide example logs and configs you already have.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to change anything. On CentOS 7, the default configuration will already include a configuration bit to set the fail2ban banaction to firewallcmd-ipset. This is in the `fail2ban-firewalld` package, which should automatically be installed.

You only need to make sure that you did not override the `banaction` somewhere else in your configuration.

Comment: Was just writing the same :D

Answer (score 0):

FirewallD is just a wrapper of iptables, which makes a easy way to manage your rules.
However, IMHO, Firewalld is better for workstation environment rather than server environment.
Thus, I recommend you to `systemctl` the following action

`disable FirewallD`

`mask Firewalld`

`enable iptables`

Then, put related `iptables` action in your `jail.local`

In my previous experience using firewalld config in fail2ban,
I found the configure doesn't reload the frewalld, which means making the rules added by fail2ban activated.

When I `firewall-cmd --reload` manually, all invalid IPs recorded by fail2ban showing in the `firewall-cmd --list-all`

In this case, using `iptables` is your faster choice or you can modify the `firewalld-xxxxx` configures.